# Codeigniter - Checking if value already exists in database with $result->num_rows == 0 not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

A user sees a coupon page, enters the coupon code and if the coupon is valid, they see a page to pick their gift (known as exploits). *(Part 1)* They can choose any exploit. And after they choose it, it saves it in database after clicking submit. **But** it only saves it in database **if** the value already does not exist in database. *(Part 2)*

So, I have finished Part 1, but Part 2 for me is not working. It saves the value in database every single time, even though the value already exists in database.

Here's my code for my controller:

```
$result = $this->model_users->insert_used_coupon($exploit, $coupon);
switch ($result) {
            case 'used_coupons':
              //do stuff
                break;

            case 'failed':
              //do stuff
                break;

            case 'success':
              //do stuff
                break;
        }
```

My model file:

```
$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $uid = $this->session->userdata('uid');

    $this->db->select('uid');
    $this->db->where('uid', $uid);
    $result = $this->db->get('used_coupons');

    if($result->num_rows == 0) {
        $data = array(
            'coupon' => $exploit,
            'exploit' => $coupon,
            'time' => $time,
            'uid' => $uid);

        $this->db->insert('used_coupons', $data);

        if ($this->db->affected_rows() === 1) {
            return 'success';
        } else {
            return 'failed';
        }

    } else {
        return 'already_exists';
    }
```

I have no idea why this issue is happening. Any hlep is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing

`if($result->num_rows == 0) {`

with

`if($result->num_rows() > 0) {`

or

`if($result->num_rows() == 0) {`

Comment: `if($result->num_rows() > 0) {` solved it. thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`num_rows` is a function, not a property.

```
if($result->num_rows() == 0) {
```